# how to get a button element to change an h1 element in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm

I am trying to make react app where I have a button that causes an h1 element on my screen to display a joke generated from an npm package. I can tell npm package has installed successfully (by checking my console.log element), but i cant seem to get the button to change the existing h1. I receive no error message when the code compiles.

```js
import React from 'react'

var oneLinerJoke = require('one-liner-joke');
var getRandomJoke = oneLinerJoke.getRandomJoke();
console.log(getRandomJoke)



function getJoke(){
  let h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
let changedH1 = document.getElementById('jokeline').innerHTML={getRandomJoke};
  return changedH1;
}

const Template = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
<h1 id='jokeLine'>Click the button to read a joke</h1>
<button onclick= 'getJoke()'>Get ready to laff</button>

    </div>
   )

 }

export default Template
```

Comment: That's not how a React component is supposed to work at all. Try reading up on [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html); the text to display in the `h1` could be part of the component state, and clicking on the button would update that state.

Answer (score -1):

Use React state to save the joke and display it to screen. Don't directly manipulate DOM if not really required. I have updated the code with state you can check this by running at your end.

I have use react hooks to use state functionality in React's functional component.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import oneLinerJoke from 'one-liner-joke';


const Template = (props) => {
 const [joke, setJoke] = useState(null);

 const getJoke = () => {
    setJoke(oneLinerJoke.getRandomJoke());
 }

  return(
    <div>
<h1 id='jokeLine'>{joke ? joke : 'Click the button to read a joke'}</h1>
<button onclick= 'getJoke()'>Get ready to laff</button>

    </div>
   )

 }

export default Template
```

Comment: Replaced this with my code. Unfortunately no effect

Comment: That should be `onClick`, the value should be a function not a string and note that `getRandomJoke` returns an *object*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you elaborate? What should be onClick? what should be a funtion and not a string?